# Icinga2 distributed monitoring - Endpoint running all the services in it's zone

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

I'm trying to setup a distributed icinga monitoring of multuple clients.

I have set up the zones as needed i.e:

1) On the master node it looks like this

```
object Zone "edge-dev" { 
  parent="master"
  endpoints=[ 
    "edge-dev-docker",
    "edge-dev-aws"
  ]
}

object Endpoint "edge-dev-docker" {}
object Endpoint "edge-dev-aws" {}
object Endpoint "icinga.master" {}

object Zone "master" {
  endpoints = [ "icinga.master" ]
}
```

constants.conf:

```
...
const NodeName = "icinga.master"

const ZoneName = "icinga.master"
...
```

2) On each client node:

```
object Endpoint "icinga.master" {
    host = "icinga.master"
    port = "5665"
}

object Zone "master" {
    endpoints = [ "icinga.master" ]
}

object Zone "global-templates" {
    global = true
}

object Zone "director-global" {
    global = true
}

object Endpoint NodeName {}

object Zone ZoneName {
    endpoints = [ NodeName ]
    parent = "master"
}
```

and constants.conf:

```
const NodeName = "edge-dev-docker"

const ZoneName = "edge-dev"
```

and

```
const NodeName = "edge-dev-aws"

const ZoneName = "edge-dev"
```

for each node

Now, I'm trying to setup some monitoring on the squid process on each client node:

```
curl -k -s -u user:pass -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT 'https://$ICINGA_HOST:$ICINGA_PORT/v1/objects/checkcommands/check_process' -d '{ "templates": [ "plugin-check-command" ], "attrs": { "command": [ "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs" ], "arguments": { "--ereg-argument-array": "$process_regex$", "-c": "$range$" }, "vars.process_regex": "", "vars.range": "1:1", "zone": "edge-dev" } }'  | python -m json.tool

curl -k -s -u user:pass -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT 'https://$ICINGA_HOST:$ICINGA_PORT/v1/objects/hosts/edge-dev-ip-docker' -d '{ "templates": [ "generic-host" ], "attrs": { "address": "ip-docker", "check_command": "ssh", "vars.os" : "Linux", "zone": "edge-dev" } }' | python -m json.tool

curl -k -s -u user:pass -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT 'https://$ICINGA_HOST:$ICINGA_PORT/v1/objects/hosts/edge-dev-ip-aws' -d '{ "templates": [ "generic-host" ], "attrs": { "address": "ip-aws", "check_command": "ssh", "vars.os" : "Linux", "zone": "edge-dev" } }' | python -m json.tool

curl -k -s -u user:pass -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT 'https://$ICINGA_HOST:$ICINGA_PORT/v1/objects/services/edge-dev-ip-aws!edge-dev-ip-aws-squid' -d '{ "templates": [ "generic-service" ], "attrs": { "check_command": "check_process", "vars.process_regex": "'/usr/sbin/squid'", "vars.range": "1:2", "check_interval": 30,"retry_interval": 30, "max_check_attempts": 3, "zone": "edge-dev" } }'  | python -m json.tool

curl -k -s -u user:pass -H 'Accept: application/json' -X PUT 'https://$ICINGA_HOST:$ICINGA_PORT/v1/objects/services/edge-dev-ip-docker!edge-dev-ip-docker-squid' -d '{ "templates": [ "generic-service" ], "attrs": { "check_command": "check_process", "vars.process_regex": "'/usr/sbin/squid'", "vars.range": "1:2", "check_interval": 30,"retry_interval": 30, "max_check_attempts": 3, "zone": "edge-dev" } }'  | python -m json.tool
```

All the objects get propagated well to the client nodes.
The problem is, that now each client executes both of the services (even the ones that are not "his", i.e. the host which "owns" the service is not the only one running it).

To make the problem clearer- now both `edge-dev-ip-aws` host and `edge-dev-ip-docker` host run both of the services `edge-dev-ip-docker!edge-dev-ip-docker-squid` and `edge-dev-ip-aws!edge-dev-ip-docker-aws`

How can I make each one run only it's own services?

Any help or hint would be appreciated :)

Comment: @dnsmichi Saw some of your posts about Icinga. Was hoping you could lend a helping hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your zones.conf should be the same across all the servers. Something like

```
object Endpoint "icinga.master" {
        host = "<IP>"
}
object Endpoint "edge-dev-docker" {
        host = "<IP>"
}
object Endpoint "edge-dev-aws" {
        host = "<IP>"
}
object Zone "icinga.master" {
        endpoints = [ "icinga.master" ]
}
object Zone "edge-dev" {
        endpoints = [ "edge-dev-docker", "edge-dev-aws" ]
        parent = "icinga.master"
}
/*
 * Global zone for templates
 */
object Zone "global-templates" {
        global = true
}
object Zone "director-global" {
        global = true
}
```

Since both `edge-dev-docker`, `edge-dev-aws` are in the same [cluster](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#high-availability-for-icinga-2-features) they'll both be able to do the checks. So if `edge-dev-aws` isn't functioning `edge-dev-docker` will do it. If you want them each separate, they'll need their own zones like:

```
object Endpoint "icinga.master" {
        host = "<IP>"
}
object Endpoint "edge-dev-docker" {
        host = "<IP>"
}
object Endpoint "edge-dev-aws" {
        host = "<IP>"
}
object Zone "icinga.master" {
        endpoints = [ "icinga.master" ]
}
object Zone "edge-dev-docker" {
        endpoints = [ "edge-dev-docker" ]
        parent = "icinga.master"
}
object Zone "edge-dev-aws" {
        endpoints = [ "edge-dev-aws" ]
        parent = "icinga.master"
}
/*
 * Global zone for templates
 */
object Zone "global-templates" {
        global = true
}
object Zone "director-global" {
        global = true
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I think I understand. Maybe the reason for the confusion was me confusing hosts with endpoints. I wanted to have hosts in zones, that would run the same checks for each host per zone. Seems like it is not possible with this layout.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)